# Is it possible to get a type of any expression using Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, expression, template-haskell, reify

Given an expression `foo`, I could declare a top-level function

```
bar = foo
```

and get the type of `foo` as `Type` by [reifying](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#g:4) `bar`:

```
case reify 'bar of
  VarI _ t _ _ -> t
```

Is there a direct way of getting the type of `foo`, without creating the redundant definition of `bar`? Ideally as function of type `Exp -> Q Type`.

Comment: Why doesn't the direct `reify 'foo` work out for you?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov `foo` just stands for an expression here, such as `1 + 2 + 3`, it's not a name.

Comment: Oh. Well, since `reify` is the only reification function of TH and since it only accepts names, I guess you're pretty much bound.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking for a function of a type like `Exp -> Q Info` or `Exp -> Q Type`, yes? TH doesn't provide such a function. The only TH function that produces an `Info` is `reify`, and no other TH type seems to expose the type information you're after. It appears that the current TH API does not provide a way to reify arbitrary expressions.

I'm not an expert in GHC's internals, but poking around in [`compiler/typecheck/TcSplice.hs`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/typecheck/TcSplice.hs) seems to confirm that `reify` works by looking up an already-compiled (and typechecked) entity and converting the compiler's existing knowledge of its type etc. into TH's `Info` type. That information wouldn't exist for an arbitrary `Exp`. I imagine we'd have to plumb the expression back through another compiler pass.