# Getting/returning the type of a function

Tags: haskell, types

Is there any way to get and return the type of a function in Haskell?

Suppose that I have this kind of function:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> String
foo a b = (show a ++ show b ++ "hello")
```

From the code above, what I actually want is to get this kind of tuple as a return value of function:

```
> getTypeTuple foo
(Int, Int, String)
```

As far as I know, the type itself cannot be treated as a part of expressions, so I guess it wouldn't be possible to have this kind of feature at the runtime in Haskell. (Static type!!)

Then will there be any similar alternative, or preprocessor feature in Haskell?

Edit: I think what I really want is the Haskell implementation of `:t` command in GHCi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Check if integer, or check type of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131552/haskell-check-if-integer-or-check-type-of-variable)

Comment: You might want to explain *why* you want such a tuple.

Comment: It is possible to keep type information until runtime using `Typeable`. However, as chepner said above, one would ask why do you need such information. Usually, this route leads to inelegant code, so one should check first if other simpler routes are available. This might be an XY problem.

Comment: My project is like a sort of meta-programming to automatically generate a bunch of Haskell code(with other language) to establish a solid mathematical(logical) model consisting the functions.

Comment: Of course the type signature of the functions will be determined when generating the Haskell code, but I need a type made of that tuple to gather the possible input/output pair. I'll be able to have them by appending a generated `newtype` declaration, but I thought it's a kind of logic duplication on the perspective of code, so I wondered if there's any way to run `:t` command at runtime. If there's no elegant way to get it, I'll just be happy to make and append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Template Haskell to do your metaprogramming, and that allows you to get the type of a function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490821/is-it-possible-to-get-a-type-of-any-expression-using-template-haskell) for how to get the type.